supabase function unable to access one table
I have a function in supabase that updates two tables (Messages and Games), I've now added a third (Users) and for some reason its unable to access it, I've added a debug_logs table to figgure out what is happening (line 31) the query
INSERT INTO debug_logs (log_message) VALUES ('TEST ' || (SELECT SUM(score) FROM "Users"));

it returns NULL but if I just ran it byitself (not in the function) it retruns the value
Really have no idea why but it seems that only the function does not have access to the Users table...
attaching the code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resolve_message_b(world_id INT, guess TEXT, user_id UUID)
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
    message RECORD;
    total_words INT;
BEGIN
    -- Fetch the message based on the world_id
    SELECT * INTO message
    FROM "Messages"
    WHERE id = world_id;

    -- Increment resolveAttempts by 1
    UPDATE "Messages"
    SET "resolveAttempts" = COALESCE("resolveAttempts", 0) + 1
    WHERE id = world_id;

    -- Check if the guess is correct (case-insensitive)
    IF LOWER(message.content) = LOWER(guess) THEN
        -- Update isResolved to true
        UPDATE "Messages"
        SET "isResolved" = TRUE
        WHERE id = world_id;

        -- Increment game score by 100 and decrement totalWords by 1
        UPDATE "Games"
        SET score = score + 100,
            "totalWords" = "totalWords" - 1
        WHERE id = message."gameId";

        -- test into log_message
        INSERT INTO debug_logs (log_message) VALUES ('TEST ' || (SELECT SUM(score) FROM "Users"));

        -- Increment user score by 100
        UPDATE "Users"
        SET score = score + 100
        WHERE id = user_id;

        INSERT INTO debug_logs (log_message) VALUES ('Updated user score for user_id: ' || user_id);

        -- Fetch the updated totalWords
        SELECT "totalWords" INTO total_words
        FROM "Games"
        WHERE id = message."gameId";

        RETURN total_words;
    ELSE
        -- Fetch the current totalWords
        SELECT "totalWords" INTO total_words
        FROM "Games"
        WHERE id = message."gameId";

        RETURN total_words;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error occurred: %', SQLERRM;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

running the query spratly. - it worked as expected
changing the RLS to allow all change by anyone including (public and anon) - did not make any changes
Would appreciate any help!

Turn off RLS on all the tables you are trying to insert into here and see if that works. Also is the Users table in the public schema?

I've figured it out. I was missing permissions on the Users table... simple
